# Sencha Touch: Hide a toolbar button in nested lists?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, nested-lists

**[Complete Code is here](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#ERFUC#iIGOp)**

**I have the following Sencha App Nested List which comprise of a toolbar button.**

[image]

**Whenever I click on any list item, I need to remove the Button which says "Tab Bar" in the lists which follows. As you can see, the button is still there which I need to remove.**

[image]

**Heres my view code**

**Sencha View Folder**

*Main.js*

```
Ext.define('firstApp.view.Main', {
extend : 'Ext.Container',
xtype : 'main',
requires: [
              'Ext.TitleBar',
              'Ext.Button',
              'firstApp.model.item',
              'firstApp.store.nList',
              'Ext.dataview.NestedList',
              'Ext.data.TreeStore'
              //'Ext.ToolBar'
              ] ,
config : {
    fullscreen : true,
    layout : 'fit',
    items : [{
        xtype : 'nestedlist',
        title: 'List View',
        displayField : 'text',
        store : 'nList',
        //toolbar:{
        toolbar:{
            items :[
                             {
                               xtype : 'spacer'
                              },
                             {
                               xtype : "button",
                               text : 'Tab View',
                               align: 'right',
                               ui : "action",
                               handler: function(){                    
                                          Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem((
                                          Ext.create('firstApp.view.view2')),
                                          {type: 'slide', direction:'left'}).show();
                                                   }
                             }
                      ]
                   }
                }
           ]
     }
});
```

**How should I go about it? Kindly Help me out**

Comment: Is it Tab View or Tab Bar?

Comment: @SudipPal the name of the button is Tab View... I have attached the snap shot as well... What i need to do is to hide this button when I am in the sub-menu of my nested list. I believe you could make out what I am trying to ask by going through the question and snapshot.

Comment: Is there any other view available for your Sub Menu list items? Like viewport or view2.. kindly paste that code as well...

Comment: I have mention a link at the bottom of my question "Complete Code Here" which is the complete code of the demo I am developing @SudipPal

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. Well it's preaty much time consuming work, because the code used one config view (toolbar), I have initially added a listner to track when the master list is clicked, so..paste this code > listeners: { itemtap: function (list, index, item, record) { console.log("itemtap : "+list+index+item+record); } }, in your main.js file after store:'nList'. Maintain the commas. If I'll get some time to look into this tonight, I'll get back to you with complete solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.senchafiddle.com/#33NZD

Here you go Pal..

What I did

1. Assigned an Id to you "Tab View Button"
2. Added 2 listeners to you nested list
3. itemtap will get the button by id and will hide it and
4. back will get the button by id and will show it

here is the code

Gave Id to button

```
xtype : "button",
                        id: "btnTabView",
                        text : 'Tab View',
                        align: 'right',
                        ui : "action",
                        handler: function(){                    
                            Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem((
                                Ext.create('firstApp.view.view2')),
                                                           {type: 'slide', direction:'left'}).show();
                        }
```

Listeners to you nested list

```
displayField : 'text',
store : 'nList',
listeners: {
    back: function( nList, node, lastActiveList, detailCardActive, eOpts ){
        if(node.getDepth() == 1){
            Ext.getCmp('btnTabView').show();
        }
    },
    itemtap: function( nList, list, index, target, record, e, eOpts ){
            Ext.getCmp('btnTabView').hide();
    }
},
```

Comment: awesome answer '+1' for that but there's one glitch, when you add back listener, it will be called whenever I go from the nth list to (n-1)th list in my nested list. So moving forward, this code works perfect but when going back, it wouldnt be the same. @SirwaniMayur. Any thoughts ?

Comment: @innocentDemon please find my updated answer. that will solve your problem. If the answer is what you expected, please mark it as correct answer

Comment: perfect. As a beginner, I got some insights on listeners and nested list node concept

Comment: you can mail me if you have any trouble in sencha touch 2

Comment: You did it @SirwaniMayur, I am happy...:-)

Comment: @Mayur if you find my question to be helpful to others, plz +1 it.

Comment: @SudipPal if you find my question to be helpful to others, plz +1 it.